# Centrar horizontalmente lista y modificar su posición manteniendo el orden al variar ancho ventana

Tags: html, css

En la lista de la demo quisiera que se mantuviese del siguiente modo para cada ancho de pantalla. Ahora funciona correctamente solo para anchos `>800px`

```
Ancho > 800px : Todos los elemementos en la misma línea
Ancho < 800 px y >550px : 2 filas centradas 3 y 3
Ancho <550px: solo elemento "SHOES" (el que tiene opciones) centrado en una línea.
```

Gracias

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
 font-size:13px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:200;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
 padding-bottom:10px;
 display:table;
 }
.lista {display:table-cell; padding-top:10px; color:black; text-align:center;}
.lista2 {display:table-row; padding-top:10px; color:black;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="lista2"><select name="products">
    <option value="shoes">SHOES</option>
    <option value="pants">PANTS</option>
  </select></li>
  <li class="lista">PRODUCT INFO</li>
  <li class="lista">PRODUCT PICTURES</li>
  <li class="lista">LOOKBOOK</li>
  <li class="lista">TERMS&CONDITIONS </li>
  <li class="lista">CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Haz mirado como funcionan las [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)? ...[Ejemplos](https://rolandocaldas.com/html5/media-queries-y-responsive-design)

Comment: Cuando necesites cambiar estilos dependiendo del tamaño de la ventana del navegador, deberás usar media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que el siguiente código hace lo que quieres:

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:200;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    padding-bottom:10px;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    box-sizing: 
    border-box; 
    padding:10px;
    color:black; 
    text-align:center;
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {  
  li{
    width:32%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {

  .lista2{
    width:100%;
  }

  .lista{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="lista2"><select name="products">
    <option value="shoes">SHOES</option>
    <option value="pants">PANTS</option>
  </select></li>
  <li class="lista">PRODUCT INFO</li>
  <li class="lista">PRODUCT PICTURES</li>
  <li class="lista">LOOKBOOK</li>
  <li class="lista">TERMS&CONDITIONS </li>
  <li class="lista">CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```